# Неизменяемые объекты

Tags: python, python-3.x, типы-данных

В Python к неизменяемым объектам относятся числа, строки и кортежи. С последними двумя все понятно, а вот касательно чисел нет. Напишем такой код:

```
a = 7
a = 5
```

В результате, внутри переменной `a` будет храниться число `5`, но ведь числа неизменяемые, как так выходит?

Comment: Переменные изменяемые, числа неизменяемые, не путайте

Answer (score 3):

Числа неизменяемые, но в вашем примере вы поменяли не число, а переменную.

Да и в питоне переменные это не объекты, хранители ссылок на объекты. Т.е. при `a = 7` переменная хранит ссылку на объект `7`, а после `a = 5` переменная теперь хранит ссылку на другой объект – `5`.

Если запустить и проверить, то увидите текущие ссылки на объекты:

```
a = 7
print(hex(id(a)), hex(id(7)))  # 0x71106160 0x71106160

a = 5
print(hex(id(a)), hex(id(5)))  # 0x71106120 0x71106120
```

Answer (score 2):

Вместо того, чтобы ставить мысленные эксперименты, проверьте на практике:

```
a = 7
b = a # Сохраним то, что в `a` прямо сейчас

a = 5 # "Изменим" (?) число в `a`

a is b # Верно ли, что `a` и `b` содержат одно и то же значение?
# => False
```

И если посмотреть на значение в `b` (оно же прошлое значение `a`, `7`), то видно, что оно осталось прежним.